# Hazelcast: Issue while adding index

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast instance whose key is of type `MyObject` and value is an enum.
Let's say one of the attributes of `MyObject` class is `date` which is of type `java.sql.Date`.

```
    class MyObject {
       private Date date;
       public Date getDate() {
         return date;
       }
       public void setDate(Date date) {
         this.date = date
       }
    }

public enum MyEnum {
  TEST_ENUM;
}
```

Also I am using predicate to filter on the keys retrieve the enum value.
For ex:

```
EntryObject entryObject = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();    
PredicateBuiler predicateBuilder = entryObject.key.get(date).isNull;
```

This is how I am trying to add index:

```
IMap<MyObject, MyEnum> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("test");    
map.addIndex("date", true)
```

But as soon as this gets executed an exception is being thrown:

```
com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'date' on class 'class com.main.constants.myEnum'
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:176)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.instantiateGetter(Extractors.java:88)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.getGetter(Extractors.java:73)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.extract(Extractors.java:57)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValueFromTargetObject(QueryableEntry.java:156)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:82)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getConverter(QueryableEntry.java:67)
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.IndexImpl.saveEntryIndex(IndexImpl.java:67)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.AddIndexOperation.run(AddIndexOperation.java:75)
```

I understand it's trying to find the index attribute in the value class

How do I get this thing working i.e. add the index on the Key rather than on the value.

Comment: What version of Hazelcast?

Comment: I suppose, you add the `date` field to the `MyEnum` class. Are you trying to do that? And, the Hazelcast requires a getter method for `date` field in the class.

Comment: @noctarius: The hazelcast version is 3.6

Comment: @Gosha: The enum class shouldn't have that field and that is what I am trying understand, that why is the index attribute being looked in the value class i.e. in the enum

Comment: Can you share the code of your MyObject class, as well as any specific class / enum for properties?

Comment: I have edited the code. There is nothing fancy in the model class and neither in the enum, a simple POJO and an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing a test I actually found your problem :-)

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.query.EntryObject;
import com.hazelcast.query.PredicateBuilder;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IMap<MyObject, MyEnum> map = hz.getMap("test");

        EntryObject entryObject = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
        PredicateBuilder builder = entryObject.key().get("date").isNull();

        map.addIndex("__key#date", true);

        map.put(new MyObject(), MyEnum.TEST_ENUM);
    }

    public static class MyObject implements Serializable
    {
        private Date date;

        public Date getDate()
        {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date)
        {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public static enum MyEnum {
        TEST_ENUM;
    }
}
```

The trick is to create the index based on the map-key and not the value which is taken by default. You already did it in your query `entryObject.key()` but missed it on the index definition `__key.date`.

Comment: I should try this out. Just a clarification: do I have to prefix "__key." to the date attribute while adding the index ?

Comment: Yes you have to. The `__key` keyword provides the same access as `EntryObject::key`, however indexing only supports the keyword since you cannot pass in an Predicate definition.

Comment: wow. never knew this. Thanks @noctarius for taking your time out and looking into this. I will try this out now and let you know.

Comment: this worked perfectly. Let me now check the performance improvement with the addition of indexes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fixed the above code and correct the key-attribute definition :)